# Backbone.js view content keep multiplying instead of clearing

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-views

I'am new to Backbone.js and this problem has really got me stumped.

A view is built up from a collection, the collection results are filtered to place each set of results into their own array and then I make another array of the first items from each array, these are the 4 items displayed.

This works fine the first time the page is rendered but when I navigate away from this page and then go back the page now has 8 items, this pattern of adding 4 continues everytime I revisit the page.

```
    // Locatore List Wrapper
    var LocatorPageView = Backbone.View.extend({

        postshop: [],
        postbox: [],
        postboxlobby: [],
        postboxother: [],
        closestPlaces: [],

        el: '<ul id="locator-list">',

        initialize:function () {        
            this.model.bind("reset", this.render, this);        
        },

        render:function (eventName) {
           //console.log(this)

        // Loop over collecion, assigining each type into its own array
            this.model.models.map(function(item){
                var posttype = item.get('type').toLowerCase();
                switch(posttype) {
                    case 'postshop':                              
                      this.postshop.push(item);
                      break;
                    case 'postbox':
                      this.postbox.push(item);
                      break;
                    case 'postbox lobby':
                      this.postboxlobby.push(item);
                      break;                          
                    default:
                      this.postother.push(item);
                }                     
              return ;
            }, this);   

        // Create a closest Places array of objects from the first item of each type which will be the closest item
            if (this.postshop && this.postshop.length > 0) {
                this.closestPlaces.push(this.postshop[0]);                      
            }
            if (this.postbox && this.postbox.length > 0) {
                this.closestPlaces.push(this.postbox[0]);
            }
            if (this.postboxlobby && this.postboxlobby.length > 0) {
                this.closestPlaces.push(this.postboxlobby[0]);
            }
            if (this.postother && this.postother.length > 0) {
                this.closestPlaces.push(this.postother[0]);
            }

        // Loop over the Closest Places array and append items to the <ul> contianer    
            _.each(this.closestPlaces, function (wine) {
                $(this.el).append(new LocatorItemView({
                    model:wine
                }).render().el);

            }, this);
            return this;
        }

    })

    // Locator single item
    var LocatorItemView = Backbone.View.extend({

        tagName:"li",

        template:_.template($('#singleLocatorTemplate').html()),

        render:function (eventName) {
            $(this.el).html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
            return this;
        },

        events: {
            "click .locator-map": "loadMap"
        },

        loadMap: function(e) {

            e.preventDefault();             
            // Instantiate new map
            var setMap = new MapPageView({
                model: this.model,
                collection: this.collection
            });

            var maptype = setMap.model.toJSON().type;
            App.navigate('mappage', {trigger:true,  replace: true});

            setMap.render();
            App.previousPage = 'locator';

        }   


    });

window.App = Backbone.Router.extend({               
    $body: $('body'),
    $wrapper: $('#wrapper'),
    $header: $('#header'),
    $page: $('#pages'),


    routes: {
               '' : '',
         'locator': 'locator'
    },          

    locator:function () {
        this.$page.empty();                                             // Empty Page

        this.places = new LocatorPageCollection();                      // New Collection
        this.placeListView = new LocatorPageView({model:this.places});  // Add data models to the collection

        this.places.fetch();

        this.$page.html(this.placeListView.render().el);                // Append the renderd content to the page
        header.set({title: 'Locator'});                                 // Set the page title
        this.$body.attr('data-page', 'locator');                        // Change the body class name
        this.previousPage = '';                                         // Set previous page for back button

    }

});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All the properties in your `Backbone.View.extend` argument are attached to the view's prototype. In particular, these properties:

```
    postshop: [],
    postbox: [],
    postboxlobby: [],
    postboxother: [],
    closestPlaces: [],
```

end up attached to `LocatorPageView.prototype` so each `LocatorPageView` instance shares the same set of arrays and each time you use a `LocatorPageView`, you push more things onto the same set of shared arrays.

If you need any mutable properties (i.e. arrays or objects) in your Backbone views, you'll have to set them in your constructor:

```
initialize: function() {
    this.postshop      = [ ];
    this.postbox       = [ ];
    this.postboxlobby  = [ ];
    this.postboxother  = [ ];
    this.closestPlaces = [ ];
}
```

Now each instance will have its own set of arrays.

Comment: Uh oh. The @mu is too short showed up and his answer is different than mine. Am I wrong? :-)

Comment: @orangewarp: Both of us could be right but there certainly is a prototype problem, each pass through `render` adds things to the same arrays so I'd expect doubling. If there were zombies involved then I'd expect tripling or quadrupling as the zombies compounded the prototype problem.

Comment: Moving the arrays to the constructor solved the issue.  Thanks for the help, I will read up on the Zombies too as it sounds like this will cause me issues in the near future.

Comment: @orangewarp: That's why we're here, right? Where do you think I learned most of my Backbone stuff?

Comment: @muistooshort: Ha! Absolutely. It's interesting to hear your words because when you're new or coming from outside comp sci, you look at user 102k and it's easy to forget they had to start at zero also. When I made the decision to get serious about improving my programming, I was at a state where I didn't even know what JSON was. About half a year later thanks to all the resources available and help I've received here, I think I'm close to producing my first serious prototype. Second, it's super gratifying to be able to share what I've learned, including mistakes.

Comment: @orangewarp: I hear you. I was at 1 not that long ago and I trained as a mathematician so I'm a self-taught outsider in CS too. And mistakes are pretty much the only thing we really learn from :)

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a classic Zombie View problem. Basically when you do this:

```
this.model.bind("reset", this.render, this);
```

in your view, you never unbind it. Thus, the view object is still bound to the model and can't be removed from memory. When you create a new view and reset, you have that listener still active which is why you see the duplicate view production. Each time you close and redo the view, you're accumulating listeners which is why it increases in multiples of 4.

What you want to do is `unbind` your listeners when you close out the view and rid your program of binds.

```
this.model.unbind("reset", this.render, this);
```

This should eliminate the pesky zombies. I'll add a link with more detailed information when I find it.

**UPDATE - added useful references**

I also ran into this problem a while back. It's quite the common gotcha with Backbone. @Derick Bailey has a really good solution that works great and explains it well. I've included the links below. Check out some of the answers he's provided in his history regarding this as well. They're all good reads.

[Zombies! Run!](http://lostechies.com/derickbailey/2011/09/15/zombies-run-managing-page-transitions-in-backbone-apps/)

[Backbone, JS, and Garbage Collection](http://lostechies.com/derickbailey/2012/03/19/backbone-js-and-javascript-garbage-collection/)